# How can I receive a webhook from Instagram in my server?

Tags: node.js, instagram

I need to receive a `PUT` request from Instagram, (via some Webhook?), but I don't found any reference. It should trigger when I/someone publish something!

Comment: You need to have an endpoint that accepts a `PUT` request and answer with the format Instagram tells you. Then use that endpoint as your webhook

Comment: Refer to the [Instagram webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/webhooks/) documentation for the details. You'll also find lots of information on implementing a webhook request receiver elsewhere in StackOverflow.